# Javascript price deduction issue

Tags: javascript, html

So I've attempted to create a system for my transactions page so that when a user buys 10 tickets, his total will be 70, however I need it so every ticket after that is sold for normal price. This is where I'm at so far, it works with some examples ( 5 adult 7 student ) for example but not others ( 9 and 2 )

I will be forever grateful if someone can find where I'm going wrong and why some numbers work and others don't. And yes I know my code is a little sloppy I apologize in advance but thank you if you can help!

```
<form id="newshow" action="required/post/saveTransaction.php" method="post" oninput="
bothTickets.value = Math.round(ticketOne.value) + Math.round(ticketTwo.value); 
var basePrice;
var TempAmt;
var newTicketValueOne;
var newTicketValueTwo;
if (bothTickets.value == 10) {
    basePrice = 70
    ticketOnePrice = 0
    ticketTwoPrice = 0
    calculation.value = Math.round(ticketOne.value * ticketOnePrice) + Math.round(ticketTwo.value * ticketTwoPrice) + basePrice;
} else if (bothTickets.value >= 10) {
    if (ticketOne.value >= 10) {
        newTicketValueOne = Math.round(ticketOne.value) - 10;
        newTicketValueTwo = Math.round(ticketTwo.value);
    } else if (ticketTwo.value >= 10) {
        newTicketValueTwo = Math.round(ticketTwo.value) - 10;
        newTicketValueOne = Math.round(ticketOne.value);
    } else if (ticketOne.value >= 5) {
        newTicketValueOne = Math.round(ticketOne.value) - 5;
        newTicketValueTwo = Math.round(ticketTwo.value) - 5;
    } else if (ticketTwo.value >= 5) {
        newTicketValueTwo = Math.round(ticketTwo.value) - 5;
        newTicketValueOne = Math.round(ticketOne.value) - 5;
    } else {
        newTicketValueOne = Math.round(ticketOne.value);
        newTicketValueTwo = Math.round(ticketTwo.value);
    }


    basePrice = 70
    ticketOnePrice = 10
    ticketTwoPrice = 7
    tempAmt =  basePrice + Math.round(newTicketValueOne * ticketOnePrice) + Math.round(newTicketValueTwo * ticketTwoPrice);
    calculation.value = tempAmt

} else {
    basePrice = 0
    ticketOnePrice = 10
    ticketTwoPrice = 7
    calculation.value = Math.round(ticketOne.value * ticketOnePrice) + Math.round(ticketTwo.value * ticketTwoPrice);
}

base.value = basePrice;
//calculation.value = Math.round(ticketOne.value * ticketOnePrice) + Math.round(ticketTwo.value * ticketTwoPrice);
totalAmount.value = Math.round(calculation.value); 
changeDue.value = Math.round(moneyGiven.value - totalAmount.value);">
    <fieldset>

    <input type="hidden" name="teamID" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['teamID']; ?>" />
    <h4>Amount of Adults</h4>
        <input class="form-control" name="ticketOne" type="number" placeholder="0">
    <br />
    <h4>Amount of Students</h4>
        <input class="form-control" name="ticketTwo" type="number" placeholder="0">
    <br />
    <h4>Money Owed</h4>
        <input class="form-control" name="totalAmount" readonly="1">
    <br />
        <h4>Money Given</h4>
        <input class="form-control" name="moneyGiven" type="number" required>
        <h4>Change due</h4>
        <input class="form-control" name="changeDue" readonly="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="bothTickets" readonly="1">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="base" readonly="1">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="calculation" readonly="1">
    </fieldset>

    <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Process"/>
          </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: Attach listeners in Javascript, not in HTML attributes, *especially* if they're more than half a line long.

Comment: So what are the prices at discount for **adults** and **students** and what are the normal prices for them? from reading the source code above I assume **10** is for adults and **7** is for students? please explain more. Thank you. Also are the discounts a random cost or minus a percentage of the original cost?

Comment: @NewToJS The only discount isn't a % change but a physical deal, if u buy 10 tickets of any kind it will only cost $70, the problem I'm having is making that $70 be the base value. Adult and Student prices will always stay the same except for when there are 10 tickets.

Comment: @DannyFanta So what are the prices for adults and students? It's relevant to know for me to make this work.

Comment: @NewToJS Adult $10 and Student $7

Comment: if more than 10 tickets are sold would you like the cheapest outcome or most expensive one: 10 students and 5 adults could be 70+50 or 70+35 depending if you want to include the 5 adults in first 10 tickets or not.

Comment: @HMR the cheapest outcome please!

Answer (score 0):

One advice: don't let the server trust values given from the client, you need to re calculate the amount and change on the server as any user can just post any values to the server.

You can do the following:

```js
var adultTickets = 0,studentTickets=0,monyGiven=0,moneyOwed=0,change=0;
const calculateValues = () => {
  if(adultTickets+studentTickets>=10){//discount, more than 10 tickets
    const adultLeft = adultTickets-10;//how many of the tickets are adult tickets
    if(adultLeft>0){//more than 10 are adult tickets
      moneyOwed = 70 + (adultLeft*10) + (studentTickets*7);
    }else{//less than 10 are adult tickets
      moneyOwed = 70 + ((studentTickets+adultLeft)*7);
    }
  }else{
    moneyOwed = (adultTickets*10) + (studentTickets*7);
  }
  change = monyGiven-moneyOwed;
}
const setHtml = () => {
  document.querySelector(`[name="totalAmount"]`).value=moneyOwed;
  if(!(change<0)){
    document.querySelector(`[name="changeDue"]`).value=change;
  }
}
const changeAdultTicket = howMany => {
  adultTickets = Math.floor(Number(howMany));
  calculateValues();
  setHtml();
}
const changeStudentTicket = howMany => {
  studentTickets = Math.floor(Number(howMany));
  calculateValues();
  setHtml();
}
const changeMonyGiven = howMany => {
  monyGiven = Math.floor(Number(howMany));
  calculateValues();
  setHtml();
}
document.getElementById("newshow").addEventListener(
  "input",
  (e)=>{
    const inputName = e.target.getAttribute("name");
    if(inputName==="ticketOne"){
      changeAdultTicket(e.target.value);
    }
    if(inputName==="ticketTwo"){
      changeStudentTicket(e.target.value);
    }
    if(inputName==="moneyGiven"){
      changeMonyGiven(e.target.value);
    }

  }
)
```

```html
<form id="newshow" action="required/post/saveTransaction.php" method="post">
  <fieldset>

    <input type="hidden" name="teamID" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['teamID']; ?>" />
    <h4>Amount of Adults</h4>
    <input class="form-control" name="ticketOne" type="number" placeholder="0" step="1">
    <br />
    <h4>Amount of Students</h4>
    <input class="form-control" name="ticketTwo" type="number" placeholder="0" step="1">
    <br />
    <h4>Money Owed</h4>
    <input class="form-control" name="totalAmount" readonly="1">
    <br />
    <h4>Money Given</h4>
    <input class="form-control" name="moneyGiven" type="number" required>
    <h4>Change due</h4>
    <input class="form-control" name="changeDue" readonly="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="bothTickets" readonly="1">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="base" readonly="1">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="calculation" readonly="1">
  </fieldset>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Process" />
  </div>
</form>
```